# Reloading various table views with same reuseidentifier

Tags: swift, ios10, nsnotificationcenter, uitableview, reloaddata

I have several common "table views" with cells having the same name: `"LiveViewCell"`, which I would like to reload with data created in a `view controller`.
Only the next `view controller` gets the `reloadData()` call as a `notification`, and not even the current one sending the data gets it.

This is the code I implemented in all view controllers:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewLiveCells: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reloadLive),name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
}

func reloadLive(notification: NSNotification) {
    tableViewLiveCells.reloadData()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return NT.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewLiveCells.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LiveViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LiveViewCell

    let tab: Table!

    tab = NT[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureLiveCell(tab)

    return cell
}
```

This is the `LiveViewCell.swift` file

```
import UIKit


class LiveViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableNumberLeftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var guestNumbersLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var timeInTableLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableNumberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeRemainingLbl: UILabel!


    var table: Table!


    func configureLiveCell(_ NT: Table) {

        layer.cornerRadius = 20

        tableNumberLbl.text = "T" + String(NT.number)
        timeRemainingLbl.text = String(time)


    }

    func configureCell(_ NT: Table) {

        tableNumberLeftLabel.text = "T" + String(NT.number)
        guestNumbersLabel.text = "COVERS:" + String(NT.guests)
        timeInTableLabel.text = "TIME IN:" + NT.timeIn

    }



}
```

From the viewController that creates the data to reload:

```
import UIKit

var NT = Table.MyTables.newTable


class NewTableVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewLiveCells: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageTableCreated: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableNumberTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var guestNumberTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabelTable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prebooked: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func createButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("createButton tapped")

        let newNumber = Int(tableNumberTF.text!)
        let newGuestNumber = Int(guestNumberTF.text!)
        let currentTimeArrival:String? = timeLabelTable.text

        if (tableNumberTF.text?.isEmpty)! || (guestNumberTF.text?.isEmpty)! {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing input(s)", message: "Please fill in all the gaps", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back Home", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction) in

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            let presentTable = Table(number: newNumber!, guests: newGuestNumber!, timeIn: currentTimeArrival!)

            NT.append(presentTable)

            print("This is a new table with the following values")
            print(presentTable.number)
            print(presentTable.guests)
            print(presentTable.timeIn)
            print(NT.count)

            imageTableCreated.alpha = 1
            imageTableCreated.layer.zPosition = 500

            tableViewLiveCells.reloadData()

            let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
                self.imageTableCreated.alpha = 0
                self.imageTableCreated.layer.zPosition = -500

            }

        }
    }
}
```

`reloadData()` doesn't work for any `viewController` except for the previous one to this `NewTableVC` `viewController` that creates the new data, which is the first one I created after creating the other ones.
Could it be that the issue has to do with copying and pasting the same `tableViewLiveCells` to all the other view controllers?
If so, I attempted to re-create the table views but it won't let me connect the labels again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it checking that the `tableViewLiveCells` had the `delegate` and `dataSource` from the respective current `viewController` containing it, rather than the main one I used by copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints in your code and make sure your notifications are being posted, then check that each view that responds to those notifications are seeing the notification.

Your notifications are set up correctly, but you keep stating `reloadData()` doesn't work for your view controllers, when your method name is `reloadLive`. I would also double check all views setup which notifications they respond to in `viewDidLoad` as you have in  your first view controller above and that they all then have the method `reloadLive`, which will then reload your table views.

If the code above for `NewTableVC` is the complete code for that view controller then that view controller has not been added to listen for the notification and also has no method to be called in order to respond to the notification.

Comment: The complete code includes an observer, I just simplified it to avoid repeating myself and added a reload just after the data is created to prove it doesn't even update the current table view for some reason. Will try later with the breakpoints and see what happens.